Warning try-with-resources for closing super OutputStream
The bottom code compiles an input String and returns the result, as an int here. Although it works, I get a Netbeans warning telling me that the super.close() line in the close() method of the NewOutputStream class should be handled with try-with-resources. The change to:
try (super) {
    this.linkedHashMap.put(this.string,this.byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
}

doesn't work. This question might also be related to try-with-resources-when-calling-super-constructor, but I don't know how to adapt the answer to my code.
Here's my code:
package group.javacompiler;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import javax.tools.FileObject;
import javax.tools.ForwardingJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject.Kind;
import javax.tools.SimpleJavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

public class JavaCompiler {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String input = "1+2";
            String returnType = "int";

            String methodName = "methodName";
            String className = "ClassName";
            ArrayList<JavaFileObject> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            arrayList.add(new NewCharContent(className+".java",
                "public class "+className+" {\n"+
                "    public static "+returnType+" "+methodName+"() {\n"+
                "       return "+input+";\n"+
                "    }\n"+
                "}"
            ));
            LinkedHashMap<String,byte[]> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            javax.tools.JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
            compiler.getTask(null,new NewForwardingJavaFileManager(compiler.getStandardFileManager(null,null,null),linkedHashMap),null,null,null,arrayList).call();

            int result = (int) new NewClassLoader(linkedHashMap).findClass(className).getMethod(methodName).invoke(null,new Object[]{});
            System.out.println(result);
        }
        catch (Throwable throwable) {
            System.out.println(throwable.getMessage());
        }
    }
    private static class NewCharContent extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
        
        private final String charSequence;
        
        private NewCharContent(String string,String charSequence) {
            super(URI.create("string:///"+string),Kind.SOURCE);
            this.charSequence = charSequence;
        }
        
        @Override
        public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean bool) {
            return this.charSequence;
        }
        
    }

    private static class NewForwardingJavaFileManager extends ForwardingJavaFileManager<StandardJavaFileManager> {

        private final LinkedHashMap<String,byte[]> linkedHashMap;

        private NewForwardingJavaFileManager(StandardJavaFileManager fileManager,LinkedHashMap<String,byte[]> linkedHashMap) {
            super(fileManager);
            this.linkedHashMap = linkedHashMap;
        }

        @Override
        public JavaFileObject getJavaFileForOutput(final Location location,final String string,Kind kind,FileObject fileOject) {
            return new NewJavaFileForOutput(string,this.linkedHashMap);
        }

    }

    private static class NewJavaFileForOutput extends SimpleJavaFileObject {

        private final String string;
        private final LinkedHashMap<String,byte[]> linkedHashMap;

        private NewJavaFileForOutput(String string,LinkedHashMap<String,byte[]> linkedHashMap) {
            super(URI.create("string:///"+string+".class"),Kind.CLASS);
            this.string = string;
            this.linkedHashMap = linkedHashMap;
        }

        @Override
        public OutputStream openOutputStream() {
            return new NewOutputStream(this.string,this.linkedHashMap);
        }

    }

    private static class NewOutputStream extends OutputStream {

        private final String string;
        private final LinkedHashMap<String,byte[]> linkedHashMap;
        private final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream;

        private NewOutputStream(String string,LinkedHashMap<String,byte[]> linkedHashMap) {
            this.string = string;
            this.linkedHashMap = linkedHashMap;
            this.byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int intValue) {
            this.byteArrayOutputStream.write(intValue);
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            this.linkedHashMap.put(this.string,this.byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
            super.close();
        }

    }

    private static class NewClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

        private final LinkedHashMap<String,byte[]> linkedHashMap;

        private NewClassLoader(LinkedHashMap<String,byte[]> linkedHashMap) {
            this.linkedHashMap = linkedHashMap;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> findClass(String string) {
            byte[] byteArray = this.linkedHashMap.get(string);
            return defineClass(string,byteArray,0,byteArray.length);
        }

    }

}


I would remove super.close(). OutputStream is an abstract class and there aren't any parent resources backing your custom OutputStream to close anyway.

As mentioned the super implementation is known to do nothing, but the problem here is that super.close() is not necessarily called. A simple try-finally is sufficient.
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        try {
            linkedHashMap.put(string,
                    byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
        } finally {
            super.close();
        }
    }

Actually try-with-resources should have been done like:
try (NewOutputStream nos = new NewOutputStream(this.string,this.linkedHashMap)) {
    ...
}

This ensures the closing.
You would need to do some things differently, but I am glad seeing advanced compiler related code.
Here I would consider easier (more direct solvable) coding style issues.

Programming against interfaces (for more general code):
  List<String> string = new ArrayList<>();




In addition to Joop Eggen's answer, you can use a method reference as the resource to close:
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        try (Closeable _ = super::close) {
            linkedHashMap.put(string,
                    byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
        }
    }

This will only work with Closeable and if your method has declares it can throw IOException. If used with AutoCloseable the compiler will complain that you need to catch or rethrow Exception. If super.close() doesn't declare any exceptions to be thrown this also won't work.
